# Call multiple children methods from parent component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to call children methods from parent component with ViewChild:

```
...

export class Parent {
  @ViewChild(ProfileImageComponent) profileImage: ProfileImageComponent;
  ...

  updateProfile() {
    ...
    this.profileImage.updateAvatar();
  }
}
```

The problem is this only works for the first child component instance in the parent's view:

```
...
<profile-image></pofile-image> <!-- only this one gets updated -->
...
<profile-image></pofile-image>
...
<profile-image></pofile-image>
...
```

How can I call every profileImage children method so everything gets updated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `@ViewChildren` from `@angular/core` to get a reference to the components.

template:

```
<profile-image #profile></pofile-image>
<profile-image #profile></pofile-image>
<profile-image #profile></pofile-image>
```

Component:

```
import { ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChildren('profile') components:QueryList<ProfileImage>;

ngAfterViewInit(){
    // call method
   this.components.forEach(ProfileImage => {
          ProfileImage.updateAvatar();
   }); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set names to child components like:

```
<profile-image #child1></pofile-image> 
...
<profile-image #child2></pofile-image>
...
<profile-image #child3></pofile-image>
```

And declare it in parent:

```
@ViewChild('child1') profileImage1: ProfileImageComponent;
@ViewChild('child2') profileImage2: ProfileImageComponent;
@ViewChild('child3') profileImage3: ProfileImageComponent;

updateProfile() {
    ...
    this.profileImage1.updateAvatar();
    this.profileImage2.updateAvatar();
    this.profileImage3.updateAvatar();
  }
```

Comment: ProfileImage instances are dynamically generated. I rather use a ViewChildren solution...